# How can i build and return a String that contains the elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

i need an overloaded method that uses enhanced for loops to build and return a String that contains the elements in an array. This is my work:

```
 public static String arrayToString(double[] dblArray) {
    String str = "";
    for (double i : dblArray) {
        System.out.println(dblArray.toString());
    }
    return str;
  }
```

And i got output something like this:

```
 [D@232204a1
 [D@232204a1
 [D@232204a1
 [D@232204a1
```

I think this is adress of array's elements.

Comment: Can you give us example of input and expected output? BTW when we iterate we usually use element we got from array in current iteration (`dobule i`) not entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
public static String arrayToString(double[] dblArray) {
    String arr = Arrays.toString(dblArray);
    String fin = arr.substring(1,arr.length()-1).replace(",", " ");
    return fin;
}
```

Here is a solution without using a loop.

---

### Input

```
{5.12,3.14,5.6}
```

---

### Output

```
5.12  3.14  5.6
```

---

### EDIT

If you also want to use a method to print a 2D array with the same technique, you'll have to use a enhanced loop like below.

### Solution

```
public static String arrayToString(double[][] dblArray) {
        StringBuilder fin = new StringBuilder();
        for (double[] d : dblArray){
            fin.append(Arrays.toString(d).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", " ") + "\n");
        }
        return fin.toString();
    }
```

### Input

```
{{3.14,2.35}, {3.14,2.35}, {3.14,2.35}}
```

### Output

```
3.14  2.35
3.14  2.35
3.14  2.35
```

Comment: How can i do this on double[][] matrix method. In double[][] matrix the String contains a separate line for each row of the matrix

Comment: You'll have to use a loop in this case. Like for (double[] d : matrix) and use Arrays.toString() and a StringBuilder(). I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Arrays.toString(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[])).